# Что такое rvalue и lvalue?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

На разных ресурсах нашел разные определения `rvalue`, `lvalue`. 
Как же правильно?

`right value` или `read value`?

`left value` или `locator value`?

Comment: Правильно left и right

Comment: Никак не правильно, это не расшифровывается. Но произошло от right и left.

Comment: На мой взгляд, правильный первый вариант, так как взять к примеру простое выражение: a = b + c ,где (a = lvalue), a (b + c = rvalue). Судя по примеру lvalue подразумевает как бы left, но никак не read, тоже самое можно сказать и про rvalue.

Comment: О чем вопрос вообще? Почему в заголовке речь идет о "rvalue and lvalue **references**", а в теле вопроса ни слова про references нет и идет речь просто о rvalue и lvalue? В качестве "принятого" выбран ответ, который к "rvalue and lvalue references" вообще не имеет никакого отношения. Что за бессмысленная каша?

Comment: @Dima Khodan: Нет. Основным критерием качества вопросов (и ответов) на SO являются их полезность для последующих читателей. Если заголовок вопроса никак не соответствует его содержанию, то ценность вопроса - "ниже плинтуса" и он подлежит правке или удалению. Ваше "тут все прекрасно поняли суть" никакого значения не имеет. Я еще раз повторю: почему в заголовке речь идет о "**references**"? Если ваш вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к "references", то - исправляйте заголовок.

Comment: @AnT действительно, даже не заметил, что в заголовке речь о lvalue/rvlaue-reference. Заголовок поправили, теперь всё хорошо.

Comment: @AnT спасибо, буду следуть на будущее за этим.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Исходно речь шла про правую и левую части относительно оператора присваивания. Но правильного варианта такой простой расшифровки нет и быть не может. Термины так и останутся `rvalue` и `lvalue`. А вот какой в них вложен смысл чётко [прописано в стандарте](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#1). Всё это образует категории выражений.

> [image: иерархия выражений]

- **glvalue** (“generalized” lvalue)

  Выражение, чьё вычисление определяет сущность объекта, битового поля или функции.
- **prvalue** (“pure” rvalue)

  Выражение, чьё вычисление инициализирует объект, битовое поле или вычисляет значение операнда оператора, с соответствии с контекстом использования. Например, литералы `42`, `true`, `nullptr` за исключением строковых литералов, которые являются *lvalue* выражениями.
- **xvalue** (“eXpiring” lvalue)

  Это *glvalue*, которое обозначает объект или битовое поле, чьи ресурсы могут быть повторно использованы (обычно потому, что они находятся около конца своего времени жизни). Например, результат вызова `std::move` даёт выражение *xvalue*.
- **lvalue**

  Это *glvalue*, которое не является *xvalue*. Например, имя переменной, функции или члена-данных, независимо от их типа, даже переменная, имеющая  тип rvalue-ссылки, образует выражение *lvalue*.
- **rvalue**

  Это *prvalue* или *xvalue*.

Таким образом любое выражение есть в первую очередь *lvalue*, *xvalue* или *prvalue*. *rvalue* - это уже обобщение.

Comment: Только вопрос такой. Что значит неполный тип?

Comment: @DimaKhodan ```A class that has been declared but not defined, an enumeration type in certain contexts (9.6), or an array of unknown bound or of incomplete element type, is an incompletely-defined object type. Incompletely-defined object types and cv void are incomplete types (6.7.1). Objects shall not be defined to have an incomplete type.```

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, что Вы имеете ввиду под вопросом "как правильно".
rvalue и lvalue - это категории выражений.
Вот что написано в стандарте:

> — A glvalue is an expression whose evaluation determines the identity
>   of an object, bit-field, or function.
>   — A prvalue is an expression > whose evaluation initializes an object or a bit-field, or computes the
>   value of the operand of an operator, as specified by the context in
>   which it appears.
>   — An xvalue is a glvalue that denotes an object or
>   bit-field whose resources can be reused (usually because it is near
>   the end of its lifetime).
>   — An lvalue is a glvalue that is not an xvalue.
>   — An rvalue is a prvalue or an xvalue.
>
> //...
>   [Note: Historically, lvalues and rvalues were so-called because they could appear on the left- and right-hand side of an assignment (although this is no longer generally true); glvalues are “generalized” lvalues, prvalues are “pure” rvalues, and xvalues are “eXpiring” lvalues. Despite their names, these terms classify expressions, not values. — end note]

Comment: Хех. А я ещё немного заморочился переводом :)

Comment: @alexolut это же замечательно :)

Comment: Ага. Кто-то даже минусанул. Наверное, за издевательство над стандартом, который должен быть исключительно на английском :)

Comment: @alexolut это был Зуев. Шутка. А может и нет. ))