# Почему возвращаемое значение функции - ссылка?

Tags: c++, функции, ссылки

Метод `get` должен позволять обращаться к одномерному массиву (в котором хранится двумерный) так, как будто бы на такой массив память была выделена , как на двумерный.

```
#include<iostream>
struct IntArray2D {
    int  &get(size_t i, size_t j) {
        return data[i * b + j];
    }
    size_t a;
    size_t b;
    int * data;
};
IntArray2D foo(void)
{
    IntArray2D m;
    m.data= new int[25];
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        m.data[i] = 5;
    }
    m.a = 5;
    m.b = 5;
    return m;

}
int main()
{
    IntArray2D m = foo();
    for (size_t i = 0; i != m.a; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j != m.b; ++j)
            if (m.get(i, j) < 0) m.get(i, j) = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Но мне непонятно, почему функция `get` возвращает ссылку. Можете объяснить причину такой реализации функции? И как это связано с rvalue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так это вы писали код или нет? :)

Ссылка, чтобы иметь возможность написать не только

```
i = a.get(5,6):
```

(для этого можно было бы возвращать просто `int`), но и

```
a.get(5,6) = i;
```

Comment: я просто курс на stepik прохожу, код оттуда , я только foo реализовал

Comment: вот самое просто объяснение ссылки , что она синоним. Но тут получается ,что для ссылки неважно rvalue или lvalue она. То есть для ссылок это не важно или это как преимущество?

Comment: Ссылка - неконстантная - lvalue. Но никто не мешает lvalue выступить в роли rvalue...

Comment: @Elvin Да при чём тут вообще `rvalue` ????

Comment: ТС - Бред написали

Comment: lvalue (locator value) представляет собой объект, который занимает идентифицируемое место в памяти (например, имеет адрес).

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко однозначной расшифровки lvalue [нет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863457/176217).

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы возвращать ссыльку или обьект, причин несколько. Кроме тех, которые  указаны в  ответе от  `Harry`,  есть еще другие.

Если не возвращать ссыльку, то результатом вызова функции будет временный обьект, и чтобы сохранить этот результат, нужен другой обьект.

Расскажу это на примерах:
Напишем еще одну функцию.

```
int& foo2(IntArray2D& m, size_t i, size_t j) {  
    return m.get(i, j);
}
```

Этой функцией я хочу получить  конкретный элемент массива и в дальнейшем выполнять действия над ним. Если я верну не ссыльку, то в результате функции получу совершенно другой обьект, не имеющее отношение с данными переданного обьекта. Но раз я вернул ссыльку, то:

```
IntArray2D arr = foo();
foo2(arr, 0, 4) *= 10;
```

практически выполнит `arr.data[4] *= 10;`
Другой пример. Допустим у нас есть некая структура, хранящая ссыльку(чтобы работать только с,  переданным  в конструктор, обьектом):

```
struct S{
    int& n;
    S(int& k) : n(k) {};
};
```

И я хочу обьявлять обьект так:

```
S s(arr.get(1, 2));
```

Я могу это сделать, так как метод возвращает ссыльку, и мой обьект может быть инициализирован(нельзя инициализировать ссыоьку временным обьектом)

И, в дополнении:  Ссылька не занимает памяти в стеке.

Comment: `S(int& k) : n{k} {};` наверное имелось в виду, да ?

Comment: ну естественно это опечатка

Comment: Это для Вас и для меня "естественно", но может быть не очевидно ТС