# В чем разница между этими двумя инициализациями? С++

Tags: c++

int a = b;

или

int a;
a = b;

Проходил конструкторы копирования , и выяснил что при одном из них конструктор копии работает , а при другом нет! В чем же разница ?

Comment: Если речь идет о "конструкторах копирования", то почему в примере фигурирует тип `int`, у которого никаких "конструкторов" нет и быть не может?

Comment: [Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

Comment: int это скалярный тип данных. Для скалярных типов данных определенны операторы +,-,= и т.д. , смотрите ниже я привел пример, как Ваш вопрос будет выглядеть на asm, и почему разницы нет...:)

Answer (score 3):

В случае

```
int a = b;
```

объявляется переменная `a`, которая сразу же инициализируется путём копирования значения переменной `b`.

В случае

```
int a; a = b;
```

объявляется переменная `a`, происходит инициализация по умолчанию. Для типа данных `int` инициализация по умолчанию означает, что у объекта будет некое неопределённое значение.

Уже после этого переменной `a` присваивается значение переменной `b`.

Конструктор вызывается при создании нового объекта, причём конструктор копирования будет вызван, когда объект инициализируется значением другого объекта такого же типа. Когда объект инициализируется без какого-либо значения, то вызывается конструктор по умолчанию:

```
T a;     // вызывается конструктор по умолчанию.
T b;     // вызывается конструктор по умолчанию.
T c = a; // вызывается конструктор копирования.
c = b;   // конструктор не вызывается
```

Comment: В случае  int a; не   происходит инициализация по умолчанию.  В обьект записываются те данные, которые  существуют в ячейках памяти,  выделенной для обьекта, т.е. мусор. P. S.  Компилятор вполне может заменить этот код первым вариантом.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan В объекте действительно мусор, но формально это все равно инициализация, см. https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, читайте пожалуйста внимательно: я сказал, что в обьект записываются...(это та же инициализация), а замечание было по поводу инициализации по умолчанию.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan читайте, пожалуйста, внимательно: **"The effects of default initialization are: ... nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values."** Инициализация по умолчанию ничего не делает в данном случае, но это не значит, что она "не происходит" как вы выразились.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ,  неопределенное  значение не есть дефолт значение, так что я остаюсь при своем мнении: инициализация по умолчанию  не происходит. Ничего не сделано и означает, что не происходит...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ну, если вы не смогли распарсить фразу **"initialized to indeterminate values"**, то я, конечно, переубеждать не буду.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ,   думаю, что  наша дальнейшая беседа по этой теме становится не полезной, но чтобы понять, что  объявление локального обьекта int a;  это не то же самое, что  int a {}; мне не нужно читать стандарт или  учебник... В любом случаи, спасибо за обсуждение!

Comment: @ARHovsepyan `int a{}` - это **value initialization**, а `int a;` - **default initialization**.

Comment: да, я образно выразился, хотел короче, а получилось...не совсем как всегда, но все же не то

Answer (score -2):

**int** это скалярный тип, для работы с данными типами предопределены операторы **=,+,-** и т.д и ни каких конструкторов... В данном случае оператор **=** выполняет операцию копирования - значения RVALUE (b) в левую часть LVALUE (a). В вашем вопросе разнице ни какой нет, ниже будет пример, почему. В обоих случаях будет вызывать один и тот же оператор копирования **=**.

---

Для справки и тем кто минусует, про RValue. Берем вырезку из стандарта "2012 - Standarts for C++ - Drafts - **N3337** - Finall 11" про RVALUE из раздела 3.10 Lvalues and rvalues:

*An rvalue (so called, historically, because rvalues could appear on the right-hand side of an assignment expression) is an xvalue, a temporary object (12.2) or subobject thereof, or a value that is not associated with an object.*

Теперь перевод google translate:

*Rvalue (исторически так называемое, потому что rvalue может появляться в правой части присваивания expression) - это xvalue, временный объект (12.2) или подобъект или значение, которое не связано с объектом.*

---

Вывод:

Когда пишем int a = b, 1е говорим компилятору, что хотим в стеке выделить 4 байта под тип int и 2е даем компилятору команду копирования "=", что по указанному адресу записать значение b (RValue).

и на закуску... есть онлайн решение, которое переводит Ваш код в asm, https://godbolt.org/

Вот как выглядит для компилятора Ваши объявления:
к примеру:

```
int square(int b) {
    int a;
    a = b;
}

square(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

---

и следующий вариант кода:

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
int square(int b) {
    int a = b;
}

square(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

найдите отличия? Всегда надо смотреть что написано в стандарте и разбираться, как Ваш код воспринимает и обрабатывает компилятор!

Comment: обоснуйте минус, пожалуйста?!

Comment: При инициализации вида `T a = b;` никакого вызова `operator=` нет. Хотя для встроенных типов это вообще странно упоминать. Ну и `b` не является rvalue, почитайте, например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/863439/176217).

Comment: хорошо почитайте тогда стандарт N3337 https://github.com/tpn/pdfs/blob/master/C%2B%2B%20Standard%20-%202012-01-16%20-%20Working%20Draft%20(N3337).pdf и выше, раздел 3.10 Lvalues and rvalues, что такое Rvalue. И если возникает противоречие, то надо смотреть в стандарт в первую очередь.

Comment: Зачем тут ссылка на черновик восьмилетней давности? Вот вам вырезка из [свежего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417797/176217): **Historically, lvalues and rvalues were so-called because they could appear on the left- and right-hand side of an assignment (although this is no longer generally true)**

Comment: ну во первых ни где не сказано про стандарт ни слова. написал исходя из того стандарта, который проверен временем и на данный момент имеет очень большое распространение.