# std::unique_ptr и оператор '='

Tags: c++

Может кто-нибудь объяснить разницу:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> item1(new int); 
std::unique_ptr<int> item2 = item1;
```

Здесь вторая строчка вызывает ошибку, но если добавить функцию:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> createItem()
{
    return std::make_unique<int>();
}
```

и вызвать

```
std::unique_ptr<int> item2 = createItem();
```

То все будет нормально. Но почему? Разве в двух случаях не вызывается один и тот же конструктор копирования?

Comment: Конечно же нет, и ничего не мешало вам в этом убедиться самостоятельно пропустив этот кусок построчно через отладчик. Кроме того, упомянутый оператор `=` в приведенных отрывках нигде не используется.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для `std::unique_ptr` запрещено копирование. Разрешение только перемещение. При выполнении варианта с функцией и присваивание результата происходит перемещение возвращаемого результата функции в указатель. Поэтому код работает.

Чтобы работал и в первом случае можно добавить `std::move`, который приведёт аргумент к *rvalue* и позволит выполнить перемещение, а не копирование.

```
std::unique_ptr<int> item2 = std::move(item1);
```

В этом случае значение из `item1` переходит в `item2`, т.е. `item1` перестаёт владеть данными и становится пустым. Однако здесь вызывается не `operator=`, а происходит вызов перемещающего конструктора, т.к. объект `item2` только создаётся. Если бы запись выглядела так:

```
item2 = std::move(item1);
```

При условии, что `item2` создан где-то ранее, то тогда это уже было бы вызовом перемещающего `operator=`.

Comment: получается,что из функции уже возвращается r-value ?

Comment: @Вячеслав по поводу категорий выражений можете почитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863457/176217).