# Ссылка на указатель на функцию

Tags: c++

Вот так все работает отлично:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void qwer(std::function<void()> &x)
{
        x();
}

void e()
{
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
        //void (*ee)() = e;
        std::function<void()> ee = e;
        qwer(ee);
}
```

А вот так нет:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void qwer(std::function<void()> &x)
{
        x();
}

void e()
{
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
        void (*ee)() = e;
        //std::function<void()> ee = e;
        qwer(ee);
}
```

Выдает:

```
test2.cpp:18:7: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::function<void()>&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::function<void()>’
   18 |  qwer(ee);
      |       ^~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:59,
                 from test2.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:667:7: note:   after user-defined conversion: ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = void (*)(); <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]’
  667 |       function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>::
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test2.cpp:4:34: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void qwer(std::function<void()>&)’
    4 | void qwer(std::function<void()> &x)
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Почему он пишет, что `ee` это `rvalue`? Ведь это не так.

Comment: В примере лямбд нет, а вот идентификатор `ee` переиспользуется. Причем во втором случае в качестве аргумента переделается не `ee`, а временный объект `std::function<void()>`, который как раз и есть rvalue.

Comment: @user7860670 Заголовок поправил. А что значит переиспользуется?)

Comment: Там пишется не что `ee` это rvalue, а что аргумент `qwer` это rvalue.То бишь вызов на самом деле такой `qwer(std::function<void()>{ee});`

Comment: Добавьте константность и функция будет принимать временные объекты. `void qwer(std::function<void()> const &x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом случае типы формального и фактического параметров функции совпадают с точностью до ссылочности. Т.е. функция принимает `std::function<void()>&`, а передаётся ей экземпляр типа `std::function<void()>`. В более общем случае `T&` и `T` соответственно. Очевидно, что такая привязка допустима, например, такое часто используется для модификации передаваемой в функцию переменной.

Во втором случае переменная имеет тип (указатель на функцию), отличный от `std::function<void()>`, но который может быть в него преобразован. При этом для обеспечения вызова функции создаётся временная переменная типа `std::function<void()>`. (Для фундаментальных типов можно привести пример с `int` и `double`, где целочисленная переменная может быть неявно преобразована в вещественную.) И в этот раз, чтобы привязка сработала для формального типа должна быть добавлена константность (т.к. язык запрещает привязку временных объектов к неконстантным ссылкам), либо следует убрать ссылочность. В данном случае переменная `ee` как раз порождает "rvalue" (подробнее о категориях выражений можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863457/176217)), т.е. временную безымянную переменную, для которой ожидается привязка к формальному аргументу `x`.

Возвращаясь к фундаментальным типам, можно рассмотреть такие варианты:

```
void f(double d);
void g(double& rd);
void h(const double& crd);

int i = 42;

f(i); // ok. локальная переменная d инициализируется значением i
g(i); // ошибка. int не может быть преобразован в ссылку на double
h(i); // ok. создаётся временный объект типа double и инициализируется значением i
```