# Существуют ли выражения rvalue в чистом виде в соответствии с актуальным стандартом?

Tags: c++, rvalue

В данный момент изучаю семантику перемещения в ++. И не уверен в правильности понимания одного момента. В соответствии с [актуальным стандартом](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) (да и начиная с 11) в коде мы по сути можем наблюдать три случая. Это выражения `lavlue, xvalue` и `prlvalue`, где `rvalue` является подмножеством `xvalue` и `prlvalue`.

Несмотря на это, при изучении других источников я регулярно встречаю случаи, когда какое-то выражение называют `rvalue`. Я понимаю, что так делать можно, но зачем, ведь `rvalue` в чистом виде не бывает. Это всегда или `xvalue` или `prvalue`, так почему бы сразу не писать точно. По началу мне казалось, что это связано с актуальностью источников(возможно материал был создан до изменения в понятиях семантики перемещения), но это не так, подобные рассуждения можно встретить и в актуальных статьях/докладах.

Где я ошибаюсь в своих рассуждениях?

Comment: Можно говорить о lvalue vs rvalue или glvalue, xvalue и prvalue. У Вас явно как то напутано. И да, rvalue это prvalue (a+1) или xvalue ( результат move)

Comment: Возможный дубликат: [Что такое rvalue и lvalue?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/863439/176217)

Comment: что то я не туда поставил gvalue... ох

Comment: @KoVadim да, оговорился, речь о prvalue.

Comment: да, люди пишут rvalue.. но это ещё ничего. Я заметил, что не все понимают, что есть rvalue-reference и rvalue категория выражений. И путают их активно...

Comment: @KoVadim интересно, может я такой же. Верно ли будет сказать, что rvalue-reference является подмножеством rvalue-выражений?

Comment: Rvalue reference и rvalue выражения это чуточку разные штуки, хотя и встречаются рядом. Самое смешное, что rvalue reference это lvalue выражения :)